# Flood of the Close queue?

Tags: discussion, review

In recent days it seems like the Close post queue have been rather full with questions. A lot of times the question are years or months old, and are not even bumped to the front page. I frequently reach the 20 review limit for Close queue, while I have never get that much in any other queues. In fact, sometimes there is as much as 20+ questions in the queue that allow the limit to be reached in just a single session.

Is there some reasons behind the recent flood of the Close queue? Is there some sort of Great Purge in effect that I am not aware of? Why are so many old questions get closed suddenly?

Comment: By the way: we have 50 close votes, but only 20 reviews per day. I stretch my reviews by not pressing *Close* or *Edit* buttons from the queue, but rather opening the question in another tab and hitting *Skip* in the review, then voting on the question. So, the actual reviews can be spent just on those that need to be *Leave Open*, since that button only exists within the review. // Also by the way: you haven't said anything about my answer to the differentiable null-homotopy problem...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's almost certainly related to the imminent demise of the [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag. [Tim Post has made some suggestions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16427/8348) for cleaning up the questions in the tag before the tag is eliminated, and the flood is mainly due to these efforts.